# I have the following python problem for school, but I don't even have a clue where to begin with

Tags: python

At the origin of the coordinate system we place a circle with radius 1 and a square with radius 1, that is, with page 2.
The plane of the circle is πr2, so π, and the square of the square is a2, that is, 4. The square of the square covered with the circle is π / 4.

Choose two random coordinates within the square, i.e. two random numbers between -1 and 1. The probability that this point lies within the circle is equal to π / 4.

We do this a thousand times. There will be around n = 1000 × π / 4 points within the circle. If they did not know how much it was, they could actually do this experiment; with them we get the upper n, and from this n, if we turn the formula around, we calculate the value of π.
Write a program that draws out 1000 random coordinates within a square, (quietly) counts how much it is calculated in this way within the circle and in the end.

This will help you: if you write from random random * at the beginning of the program, the random () function returns a random number between 0 and 1. How to convert it into numbers between -1 and 1, consider it yourself. You also deal with mathematics yourself.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7fo0.png)

Comment: Has this question gone through Google translate? Homework dumps without any effort are not appropriate for SO but I'm having a hard time trying to understand what this question is about.

Comment: It sounds something like a Monte Carlo simulation

Answer (score 0):

Rather than giving you a complete answer... as this is a school project, that would deprive you of some learning. I'll give you some pointers:

- If you need random numbers between -1 and 1, but random.random() only gives values between 0 and 1. What do you need to do to the random numbers to get the range you need? (One simple way would be to multiply by 2 - resulting in a number between 0 and 2, then subtract by 1, to bring it to -1 to 1)
- Try pyplot for plotting the graph so you can visualise the answer to check to see if your doing the right thing.